# Moving files while preserving the folder structure

Tags: c#, strings, console

I'm writing a console application that will look through a directory and move any log files that have a date modified older than `X` days (configurable in the `app.config` file).

The problem I'm having is with the `Move` method I wrote. It works, but I think there might be a better way to write this method and eliminate the need for the `sourceRoothPath` parameter. Here's what I have (it's part of a `LogManager` class I wrote to do the checking and moving of log files):

```
public void Move(string sourceRootPath, string sourcePath, string targetPath)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourcePath))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sourcePath");

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetPath))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationPath");

    if (!File.Exists(sourcePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(sourcePath);

    try
    {
        // trimmedPath becomes the file path with all the subfolders, but without the
        // sourceRootPath that comes in front of it. i.e. it strips the value passed
        // in sourceRootPath from the value passed in sourcePath. The "+ 1" is to include the
        // trailing "\" in the path.
        string trimmedPath = sourcePath.Substring(sourceRootPath.Length + 1);
        string newPath = Path.Combine(targetPath, trimmedPath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath);

        // folderStructure is used for creating the subfolder structure I want to preserve.
        // (It is just removing the file name and extension from the newPath.)
        string folderStructure = newPath.Substring(0, (newPath.Length - fileName.Length));

        // Directory.CreateDirectory will create the entire folder structure for me; no need
        // for looping or recursive calls.
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderStructure);

        // File.Move has no ability to overwrite, so I have to delete the file if it exists in the
        // destination directory so that File.Move doesn't throw an exception.
        if (File.Exists(newPath))
            File.Delete(newPath);

        File.Move(sourcePath, newPath);
        loggingService.LogInfo("Moved file from " + sourcePath + " to " + newPath + ".");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        loggingService.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I included the `sourceRootPath` parameter because I need this method to duplicate the folder structure of the `sourcePath`, but I don't want it to include some of the top level folders.

So, for example, if I'm having this application scan a log file directory at `C:\someFolder\test\logs`, and there are some subfolders like `production\someDate` or `HR\HRSystem\someDate` etc. I want to keep the subfolder structure in the `production` and `HR` folders, but move them to a new location like `C:\test_log_archive`. So `C:\someFolder\test\logs\production\someDate` should become `C:\test_log_archive\production\someDate`, and the value I would pass for `sourceRootPath` would be `C:\someFolder\test\logs`.

**Does it make sense to remove the `sourceRootPath` and how would I do it?** I feel like I should be able to accomplish this with just `sourcePath` and `targetPath` parameters, but I can't figure out a way to do it other than the code I provided above.

Comment: You should be able to utilize a source and destination, what is the root vs source structure look like?

Comment: @Greg continuing with the example I posted in my question, `sourcePath` would be the path to the file it is moving like `C:\someFolder\test\logs\production\someDate\someLog.txt`. `sourceRootPath` would be `C:\someFolder\test\logs` because I would want to preserve the `production\someDate` folder structure. `targetPath` would be `C:\test_log_archive` with the end goal of the log file to be moved from `C:\someFolder\test\logs\production\someDate\someLog.txt` to `C:\test_log_archive\production\someDate\someLog.txt`.

Comment: To the downvoters, please write a comment so I can improve my question. Seriously. @Mat'sMug I've edited the title. Is that acceptable now?

Comment: CR community expects your code to be working as intended; not my downvote, but my guess is that "the problem" and "how can I do X?" stick out and make the post look more like a "how do I?" question, vs the expected "here's my code, does it make my ass look fat?" open feedback question that reviewers want to see on this site. See [ask] for more info; in general, if your question reads like a question, you're not asking for feedback on *any & all facets of the code*; a good CR post is usually off-topic on SO, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you do definitely need 3 parameters to do what you are trying to do**

Although I would suggest a different 3.

```
public void Move(string sourceRoot, string targetRoot, string[] relative) {
    /* Precondition checks and try-catch removed for clarity */

    string source = Path.Combine(sourceRoot, relative);
    string target = Path.Combine(targetRoot, relative);
    string folderStructure = Path.GetDirectoryName(target);

    /* etc */
}
```

This makes clear that there is shared structure under source and target, and there isn't any direct string manipulation on file and folder names. I would even be tempted to factor this out into a seperate class, e.g.

```
class DirectoryMover {
    private string source;
    private string target;

    private void Move(string[] relative) { ... }
    public void MoveAll() { /* iterate over folders calling Move */ }
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. It even gets rid of the string manipulation I really didn't want to have to do (edge cases that could break the code and whatnot). Although why did you make the `relative` parameter a string array?

Comment: @Sylverac The natural implementations of MoveAll would gather a collection of folder/file names (either with an explicit Stack<string> imperatively or recursively on the stack), and string[] matches the signature of Path.Combine, and is easy to get from a collection ( IEnumerable<>.ToArray() )

Comment: So when implementing this solution, it still leaves me with a problem. How do I get the value of `relative`? My current implementation calls the `Move` method from within a `foreach` loop that is iterating through a `List<string>` collection that contains the "expired" logs. Would I not have to do the same substring gymnastics to get the value to pass in `relative`?

Comment: no, whatever is generating the `expired` logs is presumably searching from source? As it goes through the directory structure, just keep track of the current relative path, e.g. with a Stack<string>.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to be wrong about the values returned by `System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries` etc. there doesn't seem to be a nice "directory entries relative to path" function

Comment: I'm an idiot. Of course that `List` is filled by searching the source. Thanks for all your help!